# Convert Matlab Datenumb into python datetime

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, datetime, timedelta

I have a DF that looks like this (it is matlab data):

```
    datesAvail    date
0       737272  737272
1       737273  737273
2       737274  737274
3       737275  737275
4       737278  737278
5       737279  737279
6       737280  737280
7       737281  737281
```

Reading on internet, i wanted to convert matlab datetime into python date using the following solution found here

```
python_datetime = datetime.fromordinal(int(matlab_datenum)) + timedelta(days=matlab_datenum%1) - timedelta(days = 366)
```

where matlab_datenum is in my case equal to DF['date'] or DF['datesAvail']

I get an error  `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

note that the data type is int

Out[102]:

```
datesAvail    int64
date          int64
dtype: object
```

I am not sure where i am going wrong. Any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are expecting as an output from this, but I assume it is a list?

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong, you are trying to convert a series with `int()`. The only arguments int can accept are strings, a bytes-like objects or numbers.

When you call `DF['date']` it is giving you a series, so this needs to be converted into a number(or string or byte) first, so you need a for loop to iterate over the whole series. I would change it to a list first by doing `DF['date'].tolist()`

If you are looking to have an output as a list, you can do a list comprehension as shown here(sorry, this is long);

```
python_datetime_list = [datetime.fromordinal(int(i)) + timedelta(days=i%1) - timedelta(days = 366) for i in DF['date'].tolist()]
```